# java.sql.SQLException: Message empty

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, sybase

Our application uses Spring boot + Hibernate and Sybase. It's getting some errors when running the below query

```
public interface ClientDao extends BaseRepository<Client, Long> {

    List<Client> findByShortNameIn(List<String> shortnames);

}


2016-03-10 17:41:32,809 WARN  [qtp358115395-22] SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 7738, SQLState: null
2016-03-10 17:41:32,809 ERROR [qtp358115395-22] SqlExceptionHelper - Message empty.

2016-03-10 17:41:32,809 WARN  [qtp358115395-22] SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 3805, SQLState: ZZZZZ
2016-03-10 17:41:32,810 ERROR [qtp358115395-22] SqlExceptionHelper - The token datastream length was not correct. This is an internal protocol error.

2016-03-10 18:17:43,526 INFO  [qtp358115395-24] ApplicationController - Retrieve Locates: LocateSearchRequest{pageRequest=PageRequest [page=0, size=50, orders=[id: ASC]], searchCriteria=LocateRequestSearchCriteria [requestTimestampEnd=null, requestTimestampStart=Thu Mar 10 00:00:00 CST 2016, finalDecisionTimestampEnd=null, finalDecisionTimestampStart=null, hedgeRequestTimestamp=null, group=[DD1T AU], finalDecision=[], decisionEngineResult=[], status=[PENDING], sourceSystem=[], assetCountry=null, sourceItem=null, sourceId=null, publishMode=false, replied=null, validTillTimestamp=null, search=false, locateType=[], ccn=null, client=null, securityId=null, ric=null, longSell=null, payToHoldRefs=null, includeLimits=false, needUpdateOnly=false, partial=false], retrieveAllGroupsAllowed=true, userGroups=[]}
2016-03-10 18:17:43,625 WARN  [qtp358115395-22] ServletHandler - 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224) ~[websocket-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.findByShortNameIn(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Message empty.

    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.26502.jar:na]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.handleSQLE(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.26502.jar:na]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.26502.jar:na]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.26502.jar:na]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.26502.jar:na]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.26502.jar:na]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.26502.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 101 common frames omitted
```

When I run another query using the same dao, e.g. `findAll`, it works fine. Can someone tell me what does the error mean? The input parameter shortnames is not empty at runtime.

Comment: Can you post the code inside findByShortNameIn()?

Comment: This is Hibernate method, no implementation needed.

Comment: The class extends JpaRepository eventually.

Comment: What is the code of the entity? What is the generated SQL query? What happens when you execute it from your SQL tool?

Comment: _"The token datastream length was not correct. This is an internal protocol error."_. You might want to check if you are using the latest versions of Sybase and their JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your column mapping is not equal to the table. One of your table column Name is wrong in the map you specify in hibernate setting or the annotations.